# bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

I get this warning from reactJS.NET

> bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React
>   does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can
>   safely remove this call. See LikeCon

Component looks like this

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
            var data = new FormData();
            var like = !this.state.like;
            var likeCounter = this.state.likeCount;

            data.append("catgoryType", this.state.categoryKey);
            data.append("objectId", this.state.objectId);
            data.append("like", like);

            if(like)
                likeCounter++;
            else
                likeCounter--;

            this.setState({ like: like, likeCount: likeCounter, userId: this.state.userId, categoryKey: this.state.categoryKey, objectId: this.state.objectId});

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("post", "http://localhost:2215/Home/SetLike", true);
            xhr.onload = function() {
        };
        xhr.send(data);
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { like: this.props.initialLike, likeCount: this.props.initialLikeCount, userId: this.props.userId, categoryKey: this.props.categoryKey, objectId: this.props.objectId  };
    },
    render(){
        return this.renderLikeButton()
    },
    renderLikeButton(){
        return (
                content =  
                <div className="likeCon">
                    <div className={this.state.like==true ? "likeButConAct" : "likeButCon"}>
                        <div className="likeB" title={this.state.like==true ? "Unlike" : "Like"} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        { this.state.likeCount > 0 ? <div className="likeCount">{this.state.likeCount}</div>: null}

                    </div>
                </div>
            );
    }
})
```

I uses a bind when calling the method handleClick, If I remove this I will get another exception? So what am I supose to do?

Comment: What is the other exception?

Comment: If I remove .bind then I get Error while rendering "FeedBox" to "react1": ReferenceError: FormData is not defined

Comment: Where is FormData defined?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `this.handleClick.bind(this)`. React automatically binds to the component instance, so just `this.handleClick` is needed. The actual error seems more like you've forgotten to include the class `FormData`.

Comment: FormData is used in handleClick but its not a defined class, I thought that it would be created on the fly? Im using http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html as source where the FormData also is used the same way? And when using Bind it works just fine?

Comment: `FormData` should be in IE10 and higher ... assuming that the web page is being displayed in IE10 or higher mode (or Chrome or Firefox). There also should be no difference between the `bind(this)` and without. They should be functionally identical. Have you tried to debug the flow with a breakpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `*.bind(null,this)` instead;

See [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/Xv9_kVoJJOw) for explanation.

Comment: This is mainly a link-only answer. Please include the relevant parts of the linked page so that the answer can still be understood when the link gets broken.

Comment: If binding `null` to `handleClick`, how can you expect `this.setState()` work in `handleClick`, `this` refer to `null` from my prespective

Comment: When trying to reach the link, I'm receiving following message: "This group either doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to access it. If you're sure this group exists, contact the Owner of the group and ask them to give you access."

Answer (score 2):

react automatically binds methods to this on method call.
This is helpful because it allows you to directly pass functions.
so to avoid this message just pass `null` instead of `this`.
refer:[AutoBind](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

Comment: Passing null will only generate the error `bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, previously I have this,

```
<input placeholder="URL" id="txt_url" className="form-control"
        value={this.state.url} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Removing that `.bind` call solved it

```
<input placeholder="URL" id="txt_url" className="form-control"
        value={this.state.url} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "content =  " or create a wrapping div:

```
<div>     content = 
          <div className="likeCon">
                <div className={this.state.like==true ? "likeButConAct" : "likeButCon"}>
                    <div className="likeB" title={this.state.like==true ? "Unlike" : "Like"} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    { this.state.likeCount > 0 ? <div className="likeCount">{this.state.likeCount}</div>: null}

                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

You need a root element in your return HTML.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions but the problem are still there?

Comment: `a=b` evaluate to `a` in javascript, try `console.log(a=100)` and you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Since v0.4 React autoBind for you. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html So you dont need to bind your self

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what `bind` aim to achieve, and I will explain it here.

Firstly, try to think about who will call handleClick ? i.e. there should be some code like `xxx.handleClick`, `xxx` really matter because when you call `this.setState` inside `handleClick`, `this` refer to `xxx`, and `setState` only exist in `React component`, so `xxx` should refer to the `component` to achieve what you what, that is why `.bind(this)` to `handleClick`, in order to set `this` to `React Component` inside `handleClick`

So now, go back to my first question, if you do not set `this` explicitly, what is `xxx`, In plain javascript the `onClick` callback is global which means there is no `xxx`, so `this` should refer to the global object, i.e. `window` if I am correct. However `React` set the `xxx` to `React Component` in a magic way, that is why you do not need to set it explicitly